# creating an array of numbers whose frequency resembles bell curve

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, normal-distribution

I want to create an array A [1 ,1 , 2, 2 ,2 , 5, 5 ,5 ,....] with numbers from [a,b] such that

- **An histogram** where Y-Axis is the frequency of the number in the array and X-axis is [a,b] **resembles a bell curve**.

  [Bell Curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEP6m.png)
- The **sum of frequency(i)*i** for all i in [a,b] is approximately around a large number **K**

Many functions are available in python like `numpy.random.normal` or `scipsy.stats.truncnorm` but I am not able to fully understand their use and how they can help me to create such an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first point is easy, for the second point, I'm assuming you want the "integral" of freq * x to be close to K (making each x * freq(x) ~ K is mathematically impossible). You can do that by adjusting sample size.

First step: bell curve shaped integer numbers between `a` and `b`, use `scipy.stats.truncnorm`. From the docs:

> ### Notes
>
> The standard form of this distribution is a standard normal truncated to the range [a, b] --- notice that a and b are defined over
>   the domain of the standard normal.  To convert clip values for a
>   specific mean and standard deviation, use::
>
> ```
> a, b = (myclip_a - my_mean) / my_std, (myclip_b - my_mean) / my_std
> ```

Take a normal in the -3, 3 range, so the curve is nice. Adjust mean and standard deviation so -3, 3 becomes a, b:

```
from scipy.stats import truncnorm
a, b = 10, 200
loc = (a + b) / 2
scale = (b - a) / 6
n = 100
f = truncnorm(-3,3, loc=(a+b)/2,scale=(b-a)/6)
```

Now, since frequency is related to the probability density function: sum(freq(i) * i ) ~ n * sum(pdf(i) * i). Therefore, n = K / sum(pdf(i) * i). This can be obtained as:

```
K = 200000
i = np.arange(a, b +1)
n = int(K / i.dot(f.pdf(i)))
```

Now generate integer random samples, and check function:

```
samples = f.rvs(size=n).astype(np.int)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(samples, bins = 20)
print(np.histogram(samples, bins=b-a+1)[0].dot(np.arange(a,b+1)))

>> 200315
```

[image]